# UndefinedFunction: function timediff(time with time zone, time with time zone) does not exist

Tags: mysql, sql, timezone

I am trying to do `TIMEDIFF()` with two time with time zone types. I am getting this error:

> UndefinedFunction: function timediff(time with time zone, time with
> time zone) does not exist

Does anyone know how to get around this?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results would also help.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? TIMEDIFF is a product specific function.

Comment: Upgrade or switch to a DBMS that supports the function.  See [MySQL Date and Time Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html) — that's for MySQL 8.0 (what Google showed me).  Alternatively, it's possible that `TIMEDIFF` does not (yet?) support TIME WITH TIME ZONE arguments.

Comment: @Doug Coats, how do you know OP is using MySQL? Is the error message MySQL style?

Comment: The error message looks like one produced by PostgreSQL. Please check your DBMS carefully.

Comment: I removed it, so it shouldnt be reflecting